# MySQL query select groups with 5 members or higher

Tags: mysql

I have groups and members in and i need to check now each group if it has 5 members or higher. So everything i need is to get only one row or none.
This is what i have tried so far:

```
SELECT groups.id, COUNT( user_groups.user_id ) as group_user_count
FROM groups
INNER JOIN user_groups ON user_groups.group_id = groups.id
WHERE groups.id = $group_id AND IFNULL(group_user_count, 0) >= 5;
```

But this is giving me unknown column for group_user_count

**EDIT**

Table structure design:

```
groups:
- id (PK)

users:
- id (PK)
- name

user_groups:
- id (PK)
- user_id (FK)
- group_id (FK)
```

But i think Forward's answer will solve my problem.

Comment: what about showing table structure, sample data, expected results? Those old good things that may help us to support you on your issue without having to guess??

Comment: Here, but i think Forward's answer will solve my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `where` clause, you should not use column alias, try to use `having`:

```
SELECT groups.id, COUNT( user_groups.user_id ) as group_user_count
FROM groups
INNER JOIN user_groups ON user_groups.group_id = groups.id
WHERE groups.id = $group_id 
HAVING IFNULL(group_user_count, 0) >= 5;
```